# Achievement icon does not work when new reputation

Tags: bug, ios-app

The achievement icon works when there is no new reputation. But when new reputation comes it does not work.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

[image: screen shot image]